# Integral $\int_{|z|=2} 1 dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is

$$\int_{|z|=2} 1 dz$$

Surely the integral evaluates to $z$, but what is it over $|z|=2$?

Comment: This is an integral over a contour, it doesn't make sense to say it evaluates to some (nonconstant) function of $z$. Anyway, what does the C.I.F. say?

Comment: No. The constant function $1$ is holomorphic, so the integral over a closed curve is $0$.

Comment: So how does one make the C.I.F apply to 1?

Comment: The integral almost literally asks "what is the net change in $z$ as you travel once around the contour $|z|=2$?".  The answer to that is zero, of course.

Answer (score 2):

**General case**

$$\int_{|z|=r}\ \text{d}z =  \int_0^{2\pi} r i e^{it}\ \text{d}t = r  e^{it}\bigg|_0^{2\pi}=0$$

In your case, $r = 2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$ that contains the contour $\gamma:=|z|=2$, that is a circle centre origin of radius $2$. Such a $\Omega$ is easy to select for example we choose quite arbitrarily the open ball centre origin of radius $3$ this ensures that $\gamma \subset \Omega$. Observe that $f(z)=1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and so in particular it is holomorphic on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Since $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve in $\Omega$ and using the above by Cauchy's integral theorem we can conclude:

$$\oint_{|z|=2}dz=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\int_{|z|=2}f(z)\,\mathrm dz= \int_{t=0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})2ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt$$
So here you compute 
$$ 2i\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}(\cos t+i\sin t)\,\mathrm dt=0$$